# remove time date information from file

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I saw the post on how to change time and date using touch or setfile. Is there a way to remove time and date entirely from a file? I tried xattr -c which did not work.

Comment: Which date time information ? creation, modification, access ?

Comment: @ankii, It doesn't matter as it cannot be removed, only changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The creation/modification date/time is a fixed field within the file system, and not a user-specified attribute that you can remove.

Comment: Correct, +1. I seem to recall that this could be done on earlier versions of the file system using `touch -t YYYYMMDDHHMM /Some/File/In/Filesystem`. Do you know when that was changed?

Comment: I cannot remember any time where it was possible to remove the time stamps entirely - that must have been before 1985 if so. You can zero out the timestamp, but it's still a timestamp corresponding to 1904 then.

Comment: @Seamus, Changing a files date/time stamp with `touch` is not the same as removing it. The OP explicitly says "remove" not _change_.

Comment: @user3439894: Yes, you're correct. But on the chance that the OP's objectives might be satisfied by substituting a "default" date/time in the field, I felt it might be useful to make that known.

Comment: @Seamus, The OP states they are already aware of how t change it, "_I saw the post on how to change time and date using touch or setfile._" and then asks "**Is there a way to remove time and date entirely from a file?**", so it is quite clear the objective is to remove it not change it.